# Equal height for sidebar when content varying height dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a two column page with sidebar and content, both given equal height on window load and widow resize. Page is responsive.

I am using a jquery plugin **mixitup** (https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) for dynamically arranging blocks in the content area.

The problem is to re-adjust height of sidebar when number of blocks changes and the height of the content area also changes.

[image]

Comment: wrap them in a div and put the left sidebar height:100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I've tried ways (with Javascript) to change the sizes to match like what you're asking for. Honestly, it's not a good solution.

If you wrap both the sidebar and the content in a container, then you can do this easily. I would recommend using flexbox. Your code might look something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='sidebar'>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
    flex: 1;
}
.content {
    flex: 3;
}
```

Here is a guide to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Flexbox is well-supported nowadays and can automatically keep sizes the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an easy way to do this in CSS that is cross-browser/works with older browsers, but if you are willing to use a small javascript function, you can pass in the elements you want to be the same height and it will set them all to the height of the tallest element.

```
function equalHeight($elements){
    var tallest = 0;
    $elements.height(auto);
    $elements.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.height() > tallest){
            tallest = $this.height();
        }
    }
    $elements.height(tallest);
}
```

You can then run this at page load and after any page re-sizes. You will probably want to check to see if you've gone to a stacked layout for mobile and just set the height to auto in that case.

Comment: equal height is already added. In content there is a dynamic sorting happening. When blocks rearrange, content height changes.

Comment: I edited the function to add a clearing of any heights that might have been set previously. To deal with the dynamic sorting, you can always call the function again whenever the sorting is finished.